# Rupee symbol '₹' and Nigeria naira '₦' are not supported by database. It's saving as '¿' in the database Oracle and SQL Server

Tags: database, sql-server-2008, relational-database, database-schema, oracle12c

Rupee symbol '₹' and Nigeria naira '₦' are not supported by database. It is saving as '¿' in the database Oracle and SQL Server.

Even I set as NLS_CHARACTERSET=WE8MSWIN1252 in Oracle, it's not working

Any other settings has to be done in db?

Comment: Are you sure it's your DB, not that your client/terminal/operating system isn't displaying the Unicode characters properly?

Comment: yes , its our staging database

Answer (score 4):

For SQL Server, you ***must***:

- define the column to hold this information as `NVARCHAR(n)` datatype (***not*** `varchar(n)` !)
- use the `N'...'` syntax when inserting values from SQL script to **ensure** Unicode storage

  ```
  INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable(UnicodeColumn)
  VALUES(N'₹'), (N'₦')
  ```
- use the correct **Unicode** data type for e.g. a parameter if you're inserting your values from frontend code (e.g. PHP, C#, Java)

Comment: Yes its working if im using NVARCHAR. Thanku for the reply.But It looks like using NVARCHAR is not advisable. Is that good to use? or any other solution is there to fix this issue?

Comment: @Jemi: `NVARCHAR` is the **Unicode** string type in SQL Server. It uses 2 bytes for each character - but if you **need** to store characters like this, it's your **only option** ....